# the name rtfwriter does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, itext, rtf

I'm trying to convert XML docs into rtf documents.
I can successfully perform xml to pdf conversions, but whenever I attempt to use `RtfWriter.GetInstance` or  `RtfHeaderFooters` I get the following error message:

> The name Rtfwriter does not exist in the current context

I can't seem to access any of the rtf assemblies. Has anyone encountered similar problems or has a possible solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. You should use:

```
RtfWriter2 rtfWriter = RtfWriter2.GetInstance(...);
```